# Python Fabric Git Pull Merge Message

Tags: python, git, fabric

I've got **Python Fabric** running nicely, however **I have one problem**. When doing `$ fab deploy` I always get a **Merge popup**

```
Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
```

I don't understand why it always does this. If I do the exact same command in SSH to pull my git repo it works without a merge issue.

I will say I'm on Windows 8 and pulling to linux if that matters. The Line endings shouldnt be an issue, it never has.

This is the **fabfile.py**

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.colors import *

env.user = 'username'
env.host_string = '99.99.0.99'

def deploy(branch = 'master'):
    path = '/var/www/mysite/htdocs'
    with cd(path):
        run("git pull origin {0}".format(branch))

def commit(branch = 'master'):
    local('git add -u')
    local('git add .')
    message = prompt("commit msg: ")
    local('git commit -m "{0}"'.format(message))
    local('git push origin {0}'.format(branch))
```

Comment: are your pulls fast-forwards?  It sounds like you got a rouge commit in your deployed tree.

Comment: I think you are right, might git hashes are not syncing up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is asking you to do merges because the pulls are not fast-forward merges.

Check that your branches are not farckled and you don't have rouge commits on the deployment side.

Comment: can you explain what you said ? and how to solve it ?